# Performance Issue with Teradata and Insert statement using ODBC driver

Tags: sql, odbc, teradata, database-performance

I have some performance issues using the Teradata ODBC driver and the Ado.net when using a Teradata database. Both are available in version 16.20.x. A simple INSERT statement takes between 40ms and 105ms to execute. A comparison was made with a SQLServer that is between 1 and 2ms. All SQL commands are executed exactly the same for both systems.

Create table query

```
CREATE TABLE DD_Teradata_ODBC (ID VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL, Feld1 VARCHAR (255), Feld2 VARCHAR (255), 
Feld3 VARCHAR (255), Feld4 VARCHAR (255), Feld5 VARCHAR (255), Feld6 VARCHAR (255), Feld7 VARCHAR (255), 
Feld8 VARCHAR (255), Feld9 VARCHAR (255), Feld10 VARCHAR (255), Feld11 VARCHAR (255), Feld12 VARCHAR 
(255), Feld13 VARCHAR (255) , PRIMARY KEY(ID))
```

Run this query within a for loop for abput 50.000 times.

```
INSERT INTO DD_Teradata_ODBC (ID, Feld1, 
Feld2,Feld3,Feld4,Feld5,Feld6,Feld7,Feld8,Feld9,Feld10,Feld11,Feld12,Feld13) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', 
'{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}', '{6}', '{7}', '{8}', '{9}', '{10}', '{11}', '{12}', '{13}');
```

The connection is opened once and the function ExecuteQuery is called within the for loop.

```
private static void ExecuteQuery(string query)
{
    var data = new List<string>();
    _connections.ForEach(conn =>
    {
        using (var command = new OdbcCommand(query, conn))
        {
            try
            {
                var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                var result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                data.Add($"{conn.Driver}\t {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

    });

    var line = string.Join("\t", data);
    Console.WriteLine(line);

    File.AppendAllLines(@"c:\temp\teradata_vs_sqlserver.csv", new[] { line });
}
```

Id did some performance tracing and faced out, that the Ado.net and the odbc driver behave the same.

[image: DotTrace_compare]

[image: Teradata ODBC]

It got really confusing when I made a chart out of the execution times. 
[image: execution time chart]

Does anyone have any idea what might go wrong here? What is going on with the timings?

Comment: Where are both DBMS and client located? Same server or over the network? What's the time to PING the server?

Comment: Communication is through the local area network. 

Reply from x.x.x.214: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Comment: It also doesn't matter if the primary key filed type is set to an integer

Comment: 10 to 25 inserts/second is way too low, I get 150 to 250 against a Teradata Express over the network. Is this a real Teradata system or an Express version? Reasons for slow inserts might be in order of impact: Block Level Compression, FALLBACK, Access Logging, Query Logging with details. What's the average record size? The pattern might be related to Teradata's variable size datablocks: You probably start with an empty table, every insert increases the block and results in a new block to be written. And when the maximum block size is reached, there's a block split.

Comment: Is the data random or sequential? A sequential ID is good for SQL Server's PK implemented as Clustered Index, but not for Teradata where this PK will be a hash-based Unique Primary Index.

Comment: It does not seem as if there is any query logging enabled.  

Rule UserName   "ALL"
  Rule UserId   00000000
  Rule ZoneId   00000000
      Account   (Rule for any Account)

NO RULE FOUND

The data is generated within a for loop. The PrimaryKey is the index of the loop, all field values represent a random GUID.

I've also tried to enable block compression for session, sent 100 insert statements and disabled the compression again. The query was executed using the Teradata Express Studio. No difference at all.

Comment: The latest TD Express is set to BLC and FALLBACK is mandatory. To check if the tables is compressed run COLLECT SUMMARY STATS and check the BLCCompRatio either in dbc.StatsV or SHOW SUMMARY STATS VALUES

Comment: After the Create table statement, "COLLECT SUMMARY STATISTICS ON DD_Teradata_ODBC;" was executed. Afterwards inserted 500 rows and executed "SHOW SUMMARY STATISTICS VALUES ON DD_Teradata_ODBC;" here's the result: https://pastebin.com/htEHkcx1

BLCCompRatio is set to 0.00000

Comment: @dnoeth, you think it's more a configuration issue with the database?